# Row stretching not working

Tags: css, wordpress, padding

I'm not a tech guy, so I would really appreciate your help. I'm running a Wordpress website.

The visual composer plugin, which came bundled with the theme on the website, has an option to choose to stretch row without paddings, but it doesn't make any difference if you do it. The plugin says that if it doesn't change this way, it might be because a parent container has "overflow: hidden" CSS property. I looked at the style.css for this, but there were maybe about 40 such "overflow: hidden" cases, and I don't know which one to remove.

I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: may i have link to your page so i can help you

Comment: If you right click on the element and select Inspect, your browser will show you the document tree along with the CSS applied to each element. You can most likely use that to locate which overflow hidden you need to remove.

Comment: @vahid the page is www.thejurist.co/bulgaria .
TimMalone I find it a bit confusing with this inspector. Maybe I'm not picking the correct elements to check there, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work in your case:

```
.wrapper.main .row.content-wrap {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.row.main-row {
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-right: -20px;
}
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, Rafael thanks. This almost worked, but it still has a little space on both ends that won't go away. I tried with more px on both sides but it won't go away either.
Also, can I use something like this for top and bottom spaces as well?

Comment: Beside the code above, add the following: `.wrapper.main { padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; }`

Comment: great, this worked, thanks! Any idea on how to remove the white space between the 2 sections vertically as well?

Comment: `.vc_custom_1462383817609 { margin-bottom: 0; }`

Comment: Thanks. I've input this in the theme's custom CSS, but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Where are you inserting it? I've searched the page source and didn't find it - I've found another id, but the class should be `.vc_custom_1462383817609`

Comment: Hi, that's where I've put it - http://store.picbg.net/pubpic/8D/E8/330fb1b388928de8.png . Is that correct?

Comment: Try this - `.vc_custom_1462383817609 { margin-bottom: 0 !important; }`

Answer (score 0):

u want your text be wider if u mean that use this

```
.vc_column_container>.vc_column-inner{
    padding:0px;
}
```

and u can use this in your VC custom CSS, Page or your themes CSS

Comment: Not exactly - the text is OK as it is, I want the sections of the page to be without paddings on all sides - left, right, top and bottom.
Just like it is on the demo: 
http://acoda.com/dynamix/one-page/
Thanks.